# question is about running benchmark and aging gem5

Tags: gem5

I am working on gem5, until now I ran ARM Full-system And Mcpat. In the following my project, I need to compute aging for ARM-Fullsystem.I  interest   to use your framework for computing aging ARm-fullsysytem on gem5. How can I use  your framework for my project?
and I read  paper about compute aging:"Cross-Layer Approaches for an Aging-Aware Design Space Exploration for Microprocessors".
<< and in the  paper , introduced two frameworks(extra time and RTL) and ExtraTime can be used in early design phases to allow the design of aging-aware microprocessors, while the RTL-framework is employed in later phases to fine-tune the design.">>

also I need to run spec cpu 2006 on ARM-fullsystem.can anybody say how to run spec cpu 2006 or introduce source and document about it?

Comment: The first question appears too generic, not sure how to answer. For SPEC CPU: have you managed to compile your own program and run it in fullsystem? If not, [here is an example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/b15a0e455d691afa49f3b813ad9b09394dfb02b7#gem5-buildroot-setup) that makes that easy. Then just add SPEC to the image as well, either by making it into a Buildroot package or dropping the prebuilt it into `rootfs_overlay`.